# How to render as you recieve data (render more than once in one route mount )

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, promise, request

I would like to render on the fly as I receive the data instead of waiting for everything to finish before being able to render the data.

```js
app.post('/', (req, response) => {
      var users = [{
        'username': 'test@gmail.com',
        'password': 'test'
      }]

      users.map((user, index) => {
            obj.login(index)
              .then(res => {

                obj.getBalance(index).then(scratchCards => {
                  // Render when balancé recieved
                });

                obj.getScratchCards(index).then(scratchCards => {
                  // Render when cards recieved
                });
              });
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `if(scratchCards){
//render your data
}`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale but don't "response.render('url', data}" exit the entire route function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your scenario, it's impossible. you can't do response.render because that will exit the entire route.
an http route can only return one http response, which means you can't return two different responses in one route(`/`).

my suggestion is to change your route architecture. create a `/` route, which will login the user. then, on the client side, run an AJAX requests(with axios or a different HTTP client) on routes `/getBalance`, `/getScratchCards`, and render the page accordingly.

a different solution, which is more primitive, is long pooling, which means that the client will send a request to the server, asking if there is anything new to render.
when the server will have something, it will return it.
then the client will long pool again.

another possibility is to create websockets, where the server will talk to the client.